# Using string to do 2 way binding in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to do string concatenation in Angular 4 with 2 way binding using [(ngModel)]

My JSON looks like this my component class

```js
var parent  =  { Child1 : { "SubChild":"Value"}}

private path:string=".Child1.SubChild"
```

I would like to do 2 way binding with using path string in my template , something like this

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="parent+path"></input>
```

Any thoughts how we can do this? I want to stick with path variable.

Comment: you can use pipe here ,sir. or (ngModelChange) callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Way binding doesn't work this way, Angular doesn't know where to split the string so the data gets set on 2 variables.

Possible solution:
Add an onchange to the input element, split it and assign it to the correct variables.

Hopefully this helps